# Why does my ChangeNotifier/Provider only get the initialized values during build, then notifyListeners() does nothing afterwards?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

In my main function I placed a ChangeNotifierProvider for the volume model:

```
`void main() {
   runApp(
   MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => VolumeModel())
    ], 
   home: const PrimaryScreenController()
  ),
  ));
 }`
```

These are the contents of the PrimaryScreenController class (note that I placed the vol variable there to test if the notifyListeners() and provider respond):

```
`@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double vol = Provider.of<VolumeModel>(context, listen: true).currentBackgroundMusicVolume;
    print(vol);
    playBackgroundMusic();

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: PageView(
                controller: _controller,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: [
                   const HomeScreen(),
                   LearnScreen(audioPlayer),
                   SettingsScreen(),
                ],
           ),
        ),
     ));
}`
```

The Settings screen contains instances of the SettingsSlider class I made. For example, the constructor:

`SettingsSlider(volumeValue: currentBackgroundMusicVolume, volumeLabel: "backgroundMusicVolume"),`

leads to this:

```
`class SettingsSlider extends StatefulWidget {
   double volumeValue;
   String volumeLabel;
   VolumeModel volume = VolumeModel();
   SettingsSlider({super.key, required this.volumeValue, required this.volumeLabel});

   @override
   State<SettingsSlider> createState() => _SettingsSliderState();
}

class _SettingsSliderState extends State<SettingsSlider>  {

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Slider(
        value: widget.volumeValue,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        label: widget.volumeValue.round().toString(),
        activeColor: const Color(0xffDF9676),
        thumbColor: const Color(0xff57CC85),
        onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.volumeValue = value;
              widget.volume.changeVolume(value, widget.volumeLabel);
        });
     },
   );
  }
}`
```

Finally, the volume object of VolumeModel contains the ChangeNotifier and notifyListeners:

```
`class VolumeModel extends ChangeNotifier {
VolumeModel();

double currentBackgroundMusicVolume = 100;
double currentSpeechAudioVolume = 100;
double currentSoundEffectsVolume = 100;

static String backgroundMusicKey = "backgroundMusicVolume";
static String speechAudioKey = "speechAudioVolume";
static String soundEffectsKey = "soundEffectsVolume";

  void changeVolume(double newValue, String label) {

    if (label == backgroundMusicKey) {
      currentBackgroundMusicVolume = newValue;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    else if (label == speechAudioKey) {
      currentSpeechAudioVolume = newValue;
      notifyListeners();
    }
    else if (label == soundEffectsKey) {
     currentSoundEffectsVolume = newValue;
     notifyListeners();
    }

    saveVolumeSetting(newValue, label);
}

Future<void> saveVolumeSetting(double volumeValue, String volumeLabel) async {

final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
pref.setDouble(volumeLabel, volumeValue);
//volumeLabel is either backgroundMusicVolume, speechAudioVolume, and soundEffectsVolume.
```

}`

**Why is it that the Provider.of line earlier only captures the initialized value, then the notifyListeners no longer goes up to that Provider.of? This happens although my print() shows that the values get passed down to changeVolume() and the currentBackgroundMusicVolume variable does indeed change.**

Thank you for your response and help. (Thank you for understanding; it is my first time to ask a question here.)

I tried everything I could, including using a Consumer widget. But both Provider and Consumer are unresponsive. What could possibly be the problem? Is it the widget tree or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Cause your are modifying a different instance of the model.

```
 onChanged: (double value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.volumeValue = value;

              // this should be Provider.of<VolumeModel>(context).changeVolume(value, widget.volumeLabel)
              widget.volume.changeVolume(value, widget.volumeLabel); 
        });
```

EDIT

based on how you structure your widgets, the SettingsSlider should look something like this

```
class SettingsSlider extends Stateless {
   final double volumeValue;
   final String volumeLabel;

   SettingsSlider({super.key, required this.volumeValue, required this.volumeLabel});

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Slider(
        value: volumeValue,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        label: volumeValue.round().toString(),
        activeColor: const Color(0xffDF9676),
        thumbColor: const Color(0xff57CC85),
        onChanged: (double value) {
            Provider.of<VolumeModel>(context, listen: false).changeVolume(value, volumeLabel)
        });
     },
   );
  }
}
```

then would be a responsibility of you SettingScreen to listen for model updates and pass the right values to its descendant.

Something like

```
class SettingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    
    @override
    void build(BuildContext context) {
       final volume = Provider.of<VolumeModel>(context);
       return Column(
         children: [
           SettingsSlider(volumeLabel: VolumeModel.backgroundMusicKey, volumeValue: volume.currentBackgroundMusicVolume),
           SettingsSlider(volumeLabel: VolumeModel.speechAudioKey, volumeValue: volume.currentSpeechAudioVolume),
           SettingsSlider(volumeLabel: VolumeModel.soundEffectsKey, volumeValue: volume. currentSoundEffectsVolume),
         ]
       );
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that makes sense! It worked. But now the slider button does not move even if the values get updated in the right places. What would you suggest to make the state get rebuilt? I tried putting the Provider outside setState (but inside onChanged), yet it still freezes.

Comment: how are you using the SettingsSlider widget?

Comment: btw the SettingsSlider is a stateful widget but you have no properties in the state to build on. Also note that widgets should be immutable (properties should be final)

Comment: I use the SettingsSlider class in the SettingsScreen class. From that screen, I pass the volumeLabel and volumeValue variables. Then, the SettingsSlider builds a Slider widget. Without the Provider we have added, the SettingsSlider class/Slider widget works as expected. The slider button moves based on the value. (It's as if the Provider blocks the setState() method inside onChanged.) What would you recommend?

Comment: can you post the SettingsScreen widget?

Comment: `class SettingsSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  double volumeValue;
  String volumeLabel;
  VolumeModel volume = VolumeModel();
  SettingsSlider({super.key, required this.volumeValue, required this.volumeLabel});

  @override
  State<SettingsSlider> createState() => _SettingsSliderState();
}

Comment: class _SettingsSliderState extends State<SettingsSlider>  {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slider(
      value: widget.volumeValue,
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      label: widget.volumeValue.round().toString(),
      activeColor: const Color(0xffDF9676),
      thumbColor: const Color(0xff57CC85),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        Provider.of<VolumeModel>(context, listen: false).changeVolume(value, widget.volumeLabel);
        setState(() {
          widget.volumeValue = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}